# Error with pyspark in local when I execute pytest in VS Code from Git Bash

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, pyspark, git-bash

I have the Error with pyspark in local when I execute pytest in VS Code from Git Bash.

If I execute pytest from gitbash console:

[image]

I try to debug my code when I create the spark Dataframe in Visual code, show me:

> Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

[image]

I have configured all environment of variables in my PC:

[image]

I have seen this error can be my variable Java is not configured really well, but I have checked it is properly.

Comment: if its only about Java path then yes its not correct, if you see your PATH variable you can see there is one more value which is `C:/....JAVA` and you set your own path too. SO do one thing, remove any value from `PATH` variable witch lead to JAVA. just make sure there is only one `JAVA_HOME` in system variable and which points upto `bin` dir not bin and then in `PATH`  variable add `JAVA_HOME\bin` try this

Comment: Is true, I have two  JAVA_HOME variable (system and User). I deleted path JAVA_HOME in my user account. But I have the same situación for PATH variable. Do you want to delete JAVA_HOME\bin in Path variable into user account yet? And this only is in system account

Comment: Now from git-bash I execute java -v, don´t recognize it. But if I execute jupyter notebook from git bash, pyspark work really, with this code

Answer (score 0):

But if I execute jupyter notebook from git bash, pyspark work really, with this code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoafA.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's like the version mismatch causes this. As '_PYSPARK_DRIVER_CALLBACK_HOST' has been removed during version 0.10.7([here](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/cc613b552e753d03cb62661591de59e1c8d82c74)) to 2.3, and gets back from version 2.3.1. So, you should check your Spark version, as the SPARK_HOME points to the right one(at least 2.3.1).

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987944/key-not-found-pyspark-driver-callback-host)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it when I put into the .bash_profile file the following line:

export path_java (in my pc)

In this way, when I execute pytest in bash console I pass testing without problems

Although from VS Code I don't pass test with debugger, I can continue with my python library